# javascript - accessing specific data in an array of objects

Tags: javascript

How do I pick the first value of `rowVal` of the first object (I want to print 42.00).

```
dataTest.rows = [{
  "rowHeader": "",
  "rowDesc": ["Gene Name"],
  "rowVal": [
    ["42.00", "57.00", "45.00", "48.00", "52.00", "47.00", "39.00", "38.00", "35.00"]
  ]
}, {
  "rowHeader": "",
  "rowDesc": ["Gene Source"],
  "rowVal": [
    ["38.00", "50.00", "39.00", "41.00", "45.00", "40.00", "34.00", "33.00", "29.00"]

  ]
}];
```

I tried:

```
console.log(dataTest.rows[0].rowVal[0]);
```

but it returns all the numbers in the array of `rowVal` of the first object?

Comment: `console.log(dataTest.rows[0].rowVal[0][0]);`

Comment: `rowVal` is an array of arrays, not an array of primitives: you're selecting a sub-array, not a string inside the sub-array. Go down one more level to access the first element: `console.log(dataTest.rows[0].rowVal[0][0]);`

Comment: `console.log(dataTest.rows[0].rowVal[0][0]);` You were so close. Note the extra `[0]`

Comment: Your `rowVal` is an array with an array as the first value. Note the `[[`

Comment: thank you.. I see.. i am building the code slowly to be able to load a json file into a table.. i still have some work to do before i get there

Answer (score 1):

`rowVal` is an Array of Arrays. That's why you get that result.

```
    "rowVal": [
        ["38.00", "50.00", "39.00", "41.00", "45.00", "40.00", "34.00", "33.00", "29.00"]

    ]
```

See, when you say `rowVal[0]`, it refers to an array. So, ideally, it should be something like

```
    "rowVal": ["38.00", "50.00", "39.00", "41.00", "45.00", "40.00", "34.00", "33.00", "29.00"]
```

if you want to access the elements as `rowVal[0]`. Or else, you have to change your reference to `rowVal[0][0]`.